# Is every converging sequence the sum of a constant sequence and a null sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n$ be any sequence converging to $a$ when $n \to \infty$.

Can you rewrite $a_n$ so that it is the sum of two other sequences? $$a_n=b_n + c_n,$$ with $b_n=b$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

In other words: Is a converging sequence ($a_n$) actually a null sequence ($c_n$) "shifted" by a constant ($b$)?

Or is there any counterexample where one is not allowed to do so?

Comment: You probably mean $b=a$, otherwise $c_n$ cannot converge to $0$.

Comment: "a null sequence" isn't defined.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  ProofWiki (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Null_Sequence) would disagree with you.  Although I, myself, would have upon hearing "null sequence" out of context would have assumed it meant {a_i} where all a_i = 0.  In context, I had no such impression however.

Comment: @fleablood: Ok, my bad.

Comment: Well, I wasn't familiar with the term either.  I was going to chastise about how "obviously" a null sequence would mean only zero terms and ...

Answer (score 12):

Set $b_n = a$ and $c_n = a_n - a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $a_n = b_n + c_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_n = a_n - a \to a-a = 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yeah. It's pretty easy when you can just define c<sub>n</sub> to be the set that satisfies this condition.

Comment: Of course, this only works in spaces where there is actually a subtraction operation. Converging sequences also exist in metric spaces with no such concept! But granted, the question pretty much asserts a vector space structure.

Comment: Any topologcial abelian group should do the trick. (We don’t really need abelian, but then we deal with different sequences, depending on which side we choose for our construction.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that. Simply take $b_n=a,c_n=a_n-a$. By basic properties of limits $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}c_n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n-a)=(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n)-a=a-a=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence converging towards $a$ and let define the following sequences: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},b_n:=a,c_n:=a_n-a.$$
One has: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},a_n=b_n+c_n$$
and $(c_n)$ is converging towards $0$.

Answer (score 3):

For a constant $b$ any *number* $a$ (whether it's a term in a sequence or not) can be written as $a = b + c$ where $c = a - b$ so any sequence $\{a_n\}$ can be written as $\{b + c_n\}$ where $c_n = a_n - b$ and in particular if $\lim a_n = a$ then the  sequence can be written as $\{a + c_n\}$ where $c_n = a_n - a$.  And clearly $\lim \{a_n\} = \lim \{a + c_n\} = a$.

So your question boils down to does $\lim\{b + c_n\} = b + \lim\{c_n\}$? And therefore if $b = a = \lim a_n$ does $\lim c_n = 0$.

This should be a basic proposition early on in the study of convergent sequence and the answer is: yes.

$|a - a_n| = |(a -b) - (a_n - b)| = |(a - b) - c_n|$.  So whatever $\epsilon$, $N$, $n > N$ crap that you can say about $a$ and $a_n$ can also be said about $(a-b)$ and $c_n$.

So if $c_n = a_n - b$ then $\{a_n\} \rightarrow a \iff \{c_n\} \rightarrow (a - b)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to add, subtract, multiply or divide all terms of a converging sequence with a constant, and you get another converging sequence that converges to $L+C,L-C,L\cdot C, L/C$. $C/L$ also works, provided the original sequence has no zero.

In your case, if $a_n\to a$, then $c_n:=a_n-a\to 0$ and $c_n+a\to a$. You can also have $c_n+b\to a$, provided that $c_n:=a_n-b$, and then $c_n\to a-b$.

Comment: Original sequence must have no zero and the limit has to not be zero.

Comment: @Wojowu: let's say that the sequence has no zero, even at infinity ;-)